# cordova adding file prefix in remote url

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I am doing referalCandy integration with Cordova app.
It's working fine on mobile browser but inside Cordova app it's not working

getting `file://go.referralcandy.com/purchase/sjnnafnpwv64gygz1p2al6bol.js?lightb... File not found`

It's adding prefix `file` in URL.
there are some dynamic variable. script will execute only if these will have value.
this below code is from referalCandy website.
code

```
<script ng-if="fname && lname && email && amount && currency && timestamp && externalReferenceId && signature">
(function(e) {
    var t, n, r, i, s, o, u, a, f, l, c, h, p, d, v;
    z = "script";
    l = "refcandy-purchase-js";
    c = "refcandy-popsicle";
    p = "go.referralcandy.com/purchase/";
    t = "data-app-id";
    r = {
        email: "a",
        fname: "b",
        lname: "c",
        amount: "d",
        currency: "e",
        "accepts-marketing": "f",
        timestamp: "g",
        "referral-code": "h",
        locale: "i",
        "external-reference-id": "k",
        signature: "ab"
    };
    i = e.getElementsByTagName(z)[0];
    s = function(e, t) {
        if (t) {
            return "" + e + "=" + encodeURIComponent(t)
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    };
    d = function(e) {
        return "" + p + h.getAttribute(t) + ".js?lightbox=1&aa=75&"
    };
    if (!e.getElementById(l)) {
        h = e.getElementById(c);
        if (h) {
            o = e.createElement(z);
            o.id = l;
            a = function() {
                var e;
                e = [];
                for (n in r) {
                    u = r[n];
                    v = h.getAttribute("data-" + n);
                    e.push(s(u, v))
                }
                return e
            }();
            o.src = "" + e.location.protocol + "//" + d(h.getAttribute(t)) + a.join("&");
            return i.parentNode.insertBefore(o, i)
        }
    }
})(document);
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?